# Jupyter notebook module not found

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I forked a Github Repo and added a module in a new branch.
Now I wanted to show my changes by adding a jupyter notebook.

When I run jupyter though, the newly created module cannot be imported / found.

Now Iam wondering what Iam doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any advice,

cheers,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there are two options. Either, you have the imports in a .py file and are able to import them via the import statement as usual or you copy the contents to be shown into respective cells in the notebook itself and then run these cells to have the classes available. The latter approach is either a work-around or a good way to present everything you have done nicely on the same page. But generally, if the paths to your import files are correctly specified, imports should work as usual.

I would start checking whether the files are actually all in the folders where they are supposed to be. And make sure that all required files (containing import contents) are present on the same branch on which you also want to store and run your notebook.

Comment: Hi Daniel and thanks for the quick reply! The files are in the correct folder, though it seems that the notebook starts and looks at the master branch instead of the actual branch Iam working on. /M

Comment: As far as I know, there is no means of knowing for the notebook on which branch it is located. You can simply put it in any folder you wish and it will run. Worked with it quite extensively recently myself and errors only occured when the import files were indeed not located where they were supposed to be. Maybe try "import .fileName" instead of "import fileName" or so? And, of course, all import-relevant contents from the master branch need to be located on your notebook branch as well.